# Substituir <a> por <span> dá problemas no SEO da página?

Tags: html, html-tags

Bom, eu tenho esse html para ativar o título e o link do artigo:

```
<h1 class='post-title entry-title'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.link'> 
        <a expr:href='data:post.link'><data:post.title/></a> 
    <b:else/> 
    <b:if cond='data:post.url'> 
        <a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a> 
    <b:else/> 
        <data:post.title/> 
    </b:if> 
    </b:if>
</h1>
```

O que eu quero fazer, é substituir o `<a>` por `<span>` - veja:

```
<h1 class="http://post-title entry-title"http://>
    <b:if cond="http://data:post.link"http://>
        <span expr:href="http://data:post.link"http://><data:post.title/></span>
    <b:else/>
    <b:if cond="http://data:post.url"http://>
        <span expr:href="http://data:post.url"http://><data:post.title/></span>
    <b:else/>
        <data:post.title/>
    </b:if>
    </b:if>
</h1>
```

Ao fazer essa substituição, irá desativar o clique no título do artigo, mas, o link permanecerá visível para os mecanismos de busca.

Esse método é errado, pode prejudicar o SEO da página ou não há problemas?

Answer (score 3):

É errado sim. Isso não é HTML válido, pois o elemento `span` não possui o atributo `href`. Não sou especialista em SEO, mas diria que as chances de os buscadores ignorarem seus links são bastante altas.

Answer (score 3):

Se o que quer e anular ao ação do elemento `<a>` use o javasctipt event.preventDefault() e mantenha o seu HTML correto. Os links são de extrema importância para obter um bom SEO, mas para uma página de boa qualidade tente sempre usar os elementos para as funções para que eles foram criados. Agora se o link não aponta para nenhuma página importante do site, então pode trocar e deve trocar. Não esqueça de tirar o atributo href.

Comment: Olá @Manuel Gerardo Pereira, eu já tinha visto esta possibilidade de utilizar javascript para anular este efeito. Minha dúvida era em relação a tag <span> (já fui esclarecido a respeito)! Acho que não vou retirar o link do artigo - essa modificação era apenas para estética! Queria deixar o título dos artigos do meu blog, igual aos títulos dos artigos dos blog feitos em WordPress. Muito obrigado a todos pelos esclarecimentos.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Se a questão é estética, você pode "disfarçar" o link com CSS.